# Guzzle Import error in YII framework

Tags: php, yii, guzzle

I am importing Guzzle library in a Yii project and getting error.

Way of importing

```
    Yii::import('application.vendor.Guzzle'); 
    require_once(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendor.Guzzle.Http').'/Client.php');      
    $response = Guzzle::get('http://guzzlephp.org');
```

Error

```
    Fatal error: Class 'Guzzle\Common\AbstractHasDispatcher' not found in C:\wamp\www\yiiproject\protected\vendor\Guzzle\Http\Client.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
Yii::import('application.vendor.Guzzle.*');
```

Right now you are only importing 1 class. You are also including another but the rest of the classes are no where to be found because Yii does not know where to find them.

Better yet, use composer to get guzzle. Composer will create an autoload file that you can easily import with Yii and will in turn load everything else.

Comment: How do you use the `composer` method? I tried putting `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` at the top of the file. It didn't work.

Comment: I have not worked with yii1 for a long time now, i have not kept up with if / how it works with composer. Probably it is best to ask on the yii forums.